Order Detail Pages in Woocommerce (formatted billing address)
The billing state is correctly being display in checkout page and is required for all countries but for some reason it's not being displayed neither in the order detail pages (thankyou page + order admin page) and emails except for United States even though the state is correctly saved in the database.
The problem is with 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address'.
The data is available (unformatted address) but for some reason woocommerce does not display it in the billing address.
I don't want to add a custom billing_state field but rather to ensure that the state is displayed not only for the US (country code) but for all countries.
I'm well aware that most countries don't have states, which is why : The billing_state label is worded as follows: State/Province/Region/District.

Does the saved states that don't get displayed are saved state codes in the database? Are you using some other custom code that can interact? Note that in WooCommerce, states should be saved to the database as 2 (or 3 digits) codes.

even though the state is correctly saved in the database.
Like i said before they are saved in the database for all countries but only being displayed for US.
Are you using some other custom code that can interact?
No.

Sorry, but with the provided details and explanations, nobody can guess by magic why you get the issue you are describing.

I've answered all your questions, what more do you want?
And if I had more in depth informations why woocommerce does this, I wouldn't have requested help.

From Stender:
I mean... Not all countries has states? What would I have to fill out in your billing state as a Danish person?
I'm well aware that most countries don't have states, which is why :
The billing state label is worded as follows: State/Province/Region/District.
